# How do I take a CSV file row into a table that I built?

Tags: python, csv, tkinter

#I get the name and the score variable from separate files, then I put them both in a CSV file line and then I cannot get them into the table because it says I only need two inputs (name, score)

```
    GetName = open("namefile.txt")
    PlayerName = GetName.read()
    GetScore = open("scorefile.txt")
    PlayerScore = GetScore.read()
    print(PlayerScore)
    print(PlayerName)
    #This is how ScoreList should look like for the enumerate to take it ScoreList = [PlayerName,PlayerScore]
    f=open("Score.csv", "a", newline="")
    tup=(PlayerName,str(PlayerScore))
    writer =csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(tup)
    f.close()

    with open('Score.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
        readCSV = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        print(readCSV)
        for row in readCSV:
            #print(row)
            ScoreList = row

    for i, (name, score) in enumerate(ScoreList, start=1):
        LeaderList.insert("", "end", values=(i, name, score))
```

Comment: `ScoreList = row` -- you're storing only the last row in the variable ScoreList. You perhaps meant to do `ScoreList = []` before the loop and `ScoreList.append(row)` within the loop.

Comment: The error is: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: Read my comment above again.

Comment: You should check the content of `ScoreList` using `print(ScoreList)` before the for loop and you will know what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Pandas you can easily do it

```
import pandas as pd 
table = pd.read_csv('Score.csv')
```

Comment: Where should that be added?

Comment: Yeah, using Pandas will help you a lot for data management. There are some good guides you can find, like this one: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html